# Как вернуть панель меню в Pycharm?

Tags: gui, pycharm

После обновления Pycharm куда-то пропало главное меню, и теперь окно выглядит вот так (см. фото)[image: нет панели меню]

Что делать? Как вернуть вкладки File, View и пр.?

Comment: @insolor спасибо. вот это я динозавр...

Answer (score 3):

Все команды меню дублируются в Actions в диалоге, открывающемся после двойного нажатия на <kbd>Shift</kbd>. В этом диалоге нужно в поле поиска ввести `Main Menu`, нажать на пункт `View | Appearance: Main Menu`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]